# Where is BSD.pkg on OS X 10.9?

Tags: macos, apache

I want to extract BSD.pkg file and pull some apache configuration file to cover my apache http.conf file.

I locate in `/Library/Receipts/`, But the `BSD.pkg` file is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pkg is also in the "OS X Install ESD" this one should not be empty.

to get it just download mavericks from app store

make a right click and show package contents there should be an "OS X Install ESD".dmg

mount it

now you should find BSD.pkg under -> /Volumes/OS X Install ESD/Packages/BSD.pkg

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I Click download button on the AppStore, But alert me:```OS X v10.9.1 is already installed on this computer. Use the Updates page to install the 10.9 update or if you would like to download the full OS X installer click Continue.```, Did I download mavericks from AppStore will replace my current system?

Comment: No it won't. You will be able to simply quit the installer.